# Can I use the GetFolder method with a shared folder?

Tags: vba

This code functions well in my PC in a non-shared folder:

```vb
Dim ruta, pedido As String
pedido = TextPedido.Text
ruta = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Dim fs, carpeta, olApp As Object
Dim olMail, olMailItem As Variant
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set carpeta = fs.GetFolder(ruta)
```

But when I try to run it in other PC, in a shared folder there's an error 76 (The access route was not found) that highlights the GetFolder instruction.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What is the value of _ruta_ when the error occurs?

Comment: I cannot say because I'm tele-working and there is another person running the code.